# JMeter Not Recording .jsp website with embedded JS PageAction() on page links

Tags: jmeter, screen-recording

I have followed all the proxy setting guidelines prior to recording.

I am trying to Record a Http .jsp page which has backend JavaScript:PageAction(Action,Page) for each Page link on the website. I see when I click on links on the website, JMeter is not recording(capturing) the pages I navigated. Pls let me know, if there is any option.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First of all check if clicking this link really triggers a [HTTP request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods) using your [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) as if nothing is happening, i.e. in case of [anchor links](https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/html/how-to-create-an-anchor-link-to-jump-to-a-specific-part-of-a-page.html) which point to the specific part of the current document or executing client-side JavaScript you won't be able to record it using JMeter's HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder.

If there is a request but JMeter doesn't capture it - first of all check [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) for any suspicious entries. You might need to [increase JMeter log verbosity](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging/) for the HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder by adding the next line to *log4j2.xml* file:

```
<Logger name="org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy" level="debug" />
```